# How to re-trigger Airflow pipeline within a DAG

Tags: python, automation, airflow, airflow-2.x

Our company's internal airflow2 platform has some issue, it can show "success" even if we didn't get any output from the pipeline, sometimes. To avoid this happen, we hope to have automated code to check whether there's output after Airflow pipeline finished, if not, then re-run the pipeline automatically.

Do you know how can we do that?

Comment: Airflow will consider tasks as successful if no exception has been thrown. Can you `raise` an exception if no data has been generated? That way the task will be considered failed, and you can configure it (or the DAG) to be retried. If your python code has access to airflow's code, maybe you can even throw an [`airflow. AirflowFailException`](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_api/airflow/exceptions/index.html#airflow.exceptions.AirflowFailException), so the task is not even retried.

Comment: This might help deal with that fake "success" status, but can't re-trigger Airflow DAG automatically. However, thank you @BorrajaX for the insight!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do you know how can we do that?

Yes. Question answered. I want my 15 reputation points!! Gimme gimme gimme....

---

Just kiiiiding!  There is a number of things you can do, so let's go with one of the most complex scenarios to show a few different concepts (Xcom, Branching, TriggerDagRunOperators...)

Let's say your task returns the number of records generated via [Xcom](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/core-concepts/xcoms.html).

You could add a [branch operator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_api/airflow/operators/python/index.html#airflow.operators.python.BranchPythonOperator) that looks at that number, and if it's too small (in the example below, 5 or less) triggers another run of the present DAG and marks the generating task as `FAILED`.

In the example below, the `BashOperator` would be the task that generates data. As a final step, it'd return the number of records it generated (in the example below, it's just a random number between 1 and 10).

After that, we add a check that studies whether the value returned by the data-generator task (the `generate` BashOperator in the example below) is less than `"5"` and if so, we mark the generator task as `FAILED` (so it looks pretty in red) and re-trigger the DAG.

```
import pendulum
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash import BashOperator
from airflow.operators.python import BranchPythonOperator
from airflow.operators.trigger_dagrun import TriggerDagRunOperator
from airflow.utils.state import State

# Centralize task naming (DRY)
__GENERATOR_TASK_ID = 'generate'
__RERUNER_TASK_ID = 'rerun_if_failure'


def verificator_fn(data, **context):
    print(f"Previous task returned {data}")
    if int(data) <= 5:
        print(f"Data={data} is too small, sorry")
        print(f"Marking generator task '{__GENERATOR_TASK_ID}' as {State.FAILED}")
        context['dag_run'].get_task_instance(__GENERATOR_TASK_ID).set_state(State.FAILED)
        print(f"Triggering task {__RERUNER_TASK_ID}")
        return [__RERUNER_TASK_ID]
    # else... nothing to do
    print(f"Data is good. Nothing to do")
    return []


with DAG(dag_id='SO-75838115', schedule=None, catchup=False,
         start_date=pendulum.datetime(2023, 1, 1, tz="UTC"), ) as dag:
    t1 = BashOperator(
        task_id=__GENERATOR_TASK_ID,
        # The last line will be pushed to next task
        bash_command='echo "$(( ( RANDOM % 10 )  + 1 ))"',
        do_xcom_push=True
    )
    t2 = BranchPythonOperator(
        dag=dag,
        task_id="verify",
        python_callable=verificator_fn,
        op_args=[t1.output],
    )

    t3_optional = TriggerDagRunOperator(
        dag=dag,
        task_id=__RERUNER_TASK_ID,
        trigger_dag_id=dag.dag_id,
        reset_dag_run=True)

    t1 >> t2 >> t3_optional
```

An example with three runs, two of them were successful (more than "5" was returned by the `'generate'` task) and one failed:

[image]

<sub>The third (and final) successful run was triggered by the unsuccessful run just before it.
Also notice that when the `'generate'` task is successful, the TriggerDagRun step is skipped (it's displayed with a pink square)</sub>

⚠️ NOTE: This example is particularly broad, but maybe (hopefully?) easier to logically understand from a "human" point of view? But maybe you don't need to use all what is shown there "as-is". Maybe you can adapt bits and pieces to your particular situation.

There are other Airflow features that you can explore, specially if *your* code can throw an exception (or [exit](https://superfastpython.com/exit-process/) with a non-zero exit code) when no data has been generated (that will make task fail and make things easier). A couple of things that come to mind are:

1. Airflow has the ability trigger a task if one (or all, or some...) of the previous tasks have failed (see [trigger rules](https://marclamberti.com/blog/airflow-trigger-rules-all-you-need-to-know/)). If your pipeline could throw an exception if data is not generated (therefore making the generation task "Failed") you might not need the `BranchPythonOperator` task. Maybe you can just have `generate >> trigger_dag_if_generate_failed`
2. Tasks also have the ability to run a function if they failed (see [on_failure_callback](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.2.2/logging-monitoring/callbacks.html#callback-types)) Maybe you can use that in your pipeline and put the DAG re-triggering there?
3. There are a lot of interesting values exposed in the Context (see [the docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/templates-ref.html)). They expose actual Python objects that you can manipulate. You can do things like *"tell me the status of all the tasks in the current Dag**Run**"* or *tell me what happened with the previous run*... That's probably worth taking a look at.

In my experience, Airflow's source code is pretty clear to read. It's pretty well organized, and well commented. I'd invite you to take a look at it for even more possibilities. Airflow is Python with SqlAlchemy, so it should be fairly understandable if you're a bit familiar with those.